# Plotly Hoverinfo is always displaying [R Shiny]

Tags: r, docker, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have a dashboard with multiple Plotly graphs in it - Hoverinfo is working as expected (the info pops up in a small modal when hovering) but for smaller metrics the hoverinfo data permanently displays.

Additionally, this error only occurs after deploying to Docker, and I cannot replicate it in the RStudio run app function. Any suggestions?

development, hover works fine no error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeoUV.png)

prod, hover works but data is also permanently displaying:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO99F.png)

```
add_trace(x = ~crossprod, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", color = I("#3FA1D5"), 
          marker = list(line = list(color = "black", width = .8)),
          orientation = 'h', name = "name", xaxis = "x2",
          hoverinfo = 'text',
          text = ~paste('</br>variable name:', some_data,'</br>Data:', the_data ))
```

Comment: What OS are you running? Depending on that [this site might give you information you need](https://community.deepnote.com/c/showcase/plotly-in-r-project). The objective at that link is different, but there is a discussion about dependencies that might be related to the ploltly-docker interface, but I think it's Linux specific (but I could be completely wrong here).

Comment: Hi Kat,

Thanks for the reply, I didn't have the package mentioned and have added that to the Dockerfile. The hoverinfo is still displaying at all times for small values and in tiny writing, I will keep looking into errors

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was a feature added in the latest release of Plotly I found - the solution if you have the same issue is to add `texposition="none"` to prevent the hoverinfos from showing on smaller metrics

Comment: The 'textposition' property is an enumeration that may be specified as:
      - One of the following enumeration values:
            ['top left', 'top center', 'top right', 'middle left',
            'middle center', 'middle right', 'bottom left', 'bottom
            center', 'bottom right']